# integrate codeigniter website from live to local server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to  integrate codeigniter website from live to local server

but have this error
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

> Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; CI_Session has a deprecated
>   constructor
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_pconnect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:91
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\database\DB_driver.php(115):
>   CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\database\DB.php(148):
>   CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\core\Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\application\core\MY_Controller.php(29):
>   CI_Loader->database() #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\application\controllers\site\landing.php(7):
>   MY_Controller->__construct() #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(308):
>   Landing->__construct() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\index.php(202):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makan\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php
>   on line 91

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_` has been deprecated since PHP 5, and entirely removed as of PHP 7. You should not be using that driver.

Instead, have a look at either [PHP MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Find your database config file, and change the driver to:

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Your config may also look like:

```
$db['mysql'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);
```

Comment: How I can remove it <<0
down vote
accept
mysql_ has been deprecated since PHP 5, and entirely removed as of PHP 7. You should not be using that driver.>>

Comment: By changing your default database driver as noted in my answer. You can find your configuration file in your application folder. IE: `app/config/database.php`

Comment: i found it like this $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; but still same problem what i will do